# node.js yield page view to other page view stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

i want to yield other page in side the node.js page like php yeild

```
  <!--  center   -->

  <div class="row" style="min-height:500;margin:5px 10px 0px 10px;" >

  // i whant  @yield('main')  here like php 
  </div>



  <!--  footer -->
  <footer  class="row"  name="footer" >

  </footer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it you can use jQuery .load() method. Below is the example:

```
//HTML Code
<div class="row" style="min-height:500;margin:5px 10px 0px 10px;"></div>

//jQuery Code
$(".row").load("main.html"); //Path of you html file
```